# How to query a fixed number of rows ordered by date in mysql?

Tags: mysql, query-performance

I am using mysql to query a DB. What I would like to do is to query NOT the full database, but only the last 1000 rows ordered by timestamp.

I have tried to use this query which doesn't work ad I would like. I know the limit is used to return a fixed number of selected elements. But that is not what I would like. I want to query a fixed number of element.

```
select * from mutable where name = 'myschema' ORDER BY start_time DESC LIMIT 1000;
```

Any help?

Comment: What you're after is only possible if you give it a condition, something like `WHERE start_time > some_number`. MySQL can't know what "last 1000 rows ordered by timestamp" are unless it orders the rows by value (full table scan) and then takes the 1000.

Comment: What is the difference between *"return a fixed number of selected elements"* which you don't want and *"query a fixed number of element"* which you do want. Can you explain that better? Are your intentions to use this as a subquery and you are hoping to eliminate a full table scan or is there something else you are aiming for here? If it's an optimimzation/subquery thing then you may want to read up on how [mysql optimizes ORDER BY... LIMIT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/limit-optimization.html) using indexes and the like.

Comment: Jnevil yes, I don't want to scan the full table because I don't need all the values in the full table, I need only 1000 elements which are the most recent. Hope it can help to understand what I mean...

Comment: Ambiguity.  "the last 1000 rows ordered by timestamp" -- One answer (so far) assumes that "last" implies a timestamp ordering.  One answer assumes that `ids` provide the meaning of "last".  Which it it?

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr Sort Less Data**

I guess your `mutable` table has an autoincrementing primary key called `mutable.mutable_id`.

You can then do this:

```
                 SELECT mutable_id 
                   FROM mutable 
                  WHERE name = 'myschema' 
                  ORDER BY start_time DESC 
                  LIMIT 1000;
```

It gives you a result set of the ids of all the relevant rows.  The `ORDER BY ... LIMIT` work then only has to sort `mutable_id` and `start_time` values, not the whole table. So it takes less space and time in the MySql server.

Then you use that query to retrieve the details:

```
 SELECT *
   FROM mutable
  WHERE mutable_id IN (
                 SELECT mutable_id
                   FROM mutable 
                  WHERE name = 'myschema' 
                  ORDER BY start_time DESC 
                  LIMIT 1000
        )
  ORDER BY start_time DESC;
```

This will fetch all the data you need without needing to scan and sort the whole table.

If you create an index on `name` and `start_time` the subquery will be faster: the query can random-access the index to the appropriate `name`, then scan the `start_time` entries one by one until it finds 1000. No need to sort; the index is presorted.

```
CREATE INDEX x_mutable_start_time ON mutable (name, start_time);
```

If you're on MySQL 8 you can create a descending index and it's even faster.

```
CREATE INDEX x_mutable_start_time ON mutable (name, start_time DESC);
```

Comment: The subquery you're using performs what OP's original query does, why would it be faster than original query?

Comment: My subquery does **far less work** than the original query. (1) It doesn't sort the whole table just to discard most rows. (2) It can partially scan the compound index I suggested to avoid the sort step.

Comment: Since `name` is tested with `=`, the issues about `DESC` in the `INDEX` do not apply.

Comment: `INDEX(name, start_time)` also applies to the first query (without the subquery).  That is the optimal solution.

Comment: @RickJames no, it's not the optimal solution. There's a really neat way where one can use primary key and not expand index with additional data and secondary keys. You're providing false info.

Answer (score 0):

### This works only with auto_increment

The trick is to sort less data, like O. Jones mentioned. Problem is in telling MySQL how to do so.

MySQL can't know what "last 1000 records" are unless it sorts them based on the query. That's exactly what you want to avoid so you need to tell MySQL how to find "last 1000 records".

This trick consists of telling MySQL at which `auto_increment` to start looking for the data. The problem is that you're using timestamps so I'm not sure whether this fits your particular use case.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT * FROM mutable 
WHERE `name` = 'myschema' 
AND id > (SELECT MAX(id) - 1000 FROM mutable WHERE `name` = 'myschema') 
ORDER BY start_time DESC LIMIT 1000;
```

Problems:

- `auto_increments` have gaps. These numbers aren't sequential, they're unique, calculated via sequential increment algorithm. To get better results, increase the subtraction number. You might get 1000 results, but you might get 500 results - depending on your dataset
- if you don't have an `auto_increment`, this is useless
- if the timestamps inserted are required to be sorted beforehand from larger to lower, this is useless

advantages:
- primary key is used to define the value range (where id > x), therefore dataset reduction will be the fastest possible.

Comment: Another problem:  It requires a temp table and a sort.

Comment: @RickJames - there's no problem. Naturally, you didn't explain how the nonexistent problem is solved.

Comment: Can someone provide `EXPLAIN SELECT...` for that query.

Comment: @RickJames I tried to reply politely, but I just can't. Could you please click the downvote button, write your own reply and just leave me be? I don't want to do the whole rite of passage with you, I get nothing out of explaining what PK is, how to use it in smart ways and that you can perform a range scan if you wanted the fastest possible solution there is. I could also go to lengths about what using temporary and using filesort *really* is but I don't think you'd read carefully nor that you care about helping and reading about the OP's actual problem. Have a good night.